# What's the general term for street/lane/alley/avenue etc?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

Recently I was trying to explain the Dutch word [gracht](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gracht) to a friend and I found myself needing a general word for a unit of architecture which joins two places together. I thought about "route", but for me it is a little too abstract (more of a set of directions to take than a physical entity). Is there such a word in the English language? Moreover, if we also include other, nonlinear things cities are made of (plains, squares, roundabouts -- everything that has a [name plate](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Portadown_(150),_September_2009.JPG) on the buildings), is there a word for that too?

Comment: Seriously, there is no single, all-encompassing yet unambiguous term for this.  Eg, many people (at least in the US) would not regard a dead-end road or alley as a "thoroughfare".

Comment: @HotLicks True, and true for UK too. But the question asks about something which "joins two places together". A dead-end alley doesn't really do that.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Well, something that joins two places together is a "connection".

Comment: In the most abstract sense those are all *land improvements*

Comment: @Jim - That depends on your point of view.

Comment: I'm a little curious about the difficulty describing "gracht".  From my brief reading of the article, it seems that "a canal with buildings along it, kind of like in Venice" would be an adequate description.

Comment: For your second question, consider _street network_. Local street network includes open spaces and town squares along with local roads. Regional street networks are more extensive and includes collectors, arterials and freeways.

Comment: And how does it look like if we want to extend it to even **squares**?

Comment: Ignoring the "moreover", why is road?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One such word is **thoroughfare**.

> **1.** A passage or way through.
>
> **a.** In general sense; also *fig.* Now usually merged in sense **1c,** exc. in phr. ***no thoroughfare,*** no public way through or right of way here.
>
> **c.** A road, street, lane, or path forming a communication between two other roads or streets, or between two places; a public way unobstructed and open at both ends; esp. a main road or street, a highway.
>
> [OED]

[Sense 1b is marked obsolete.]

The word is most often used of paved or metalled streets, rather than paths or alleys, but the OED definition does cover those and the word could be used of them.

Comment: When a mother is yelling at her child does she typically say, "Get out of the thoroughfare!" or "Get out of the road!" or "Get out of the street!"?

Answer (score 5):

When the only maps of directions were paper, they were called ***road***maps. Any route, highway, lane, avenue, etc.. from dirt to eight-lane, can be called a ***"road"***. (US)

Answer (score 2):

**"streets"** is the generic term.  We often say "the streets of New York", "the streets of Philadelphia", and when we say that we also mean "avenues", "boulevards", "drives", etc.

Comment: Yes; we use the plural generically for thoroughfares in a city etc, and so use it far more frequently (in this sense) than _avenues_, _boulevards_, _crescents_, _ways_, _parks_ and _promenades_. In the country, _[leafy] lanes_ takes over. _Highways and byways_ covers a larger set.

Answer (score 2):

[Websters](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way): **Way**

> a thoroughfare for travel or transportation from place to place

That meaning seems to be falling somewhat into unuse.

In [1913 Websters was far more definitive](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=way&quicksearch=on&sourceid=Mozilla-search) about what all is covered:

> 1. That by, upon, or along, which one passes or processes; opportunity or room to pass; place of passing; passage; road, street, track, or path of any kind; as, they built a way to the mine. To find the way to heaven." Shak.

Derivative terms include: Freeway, highway/hiway, tollway, byway, walkway, bikeway, hallway, etc.
All may be used by wayfarers.

Answer (score 0):

The word you need is "thoroughfare," although it is not that common a word.

In a city, "street" is generally applicable to all thoroughfares, even those containing other synonyms in their proper name.

In a rural area, "road" serves the same purpose.

Comment: In the US, at least, a "route" is a numbered roadway with identifying signs at regular intervals. These routes may consist of parts of different streets or roads, and may be overseen by individual states or the federal system.

Answer (score 0):

A ***thoroughfare*** is defined by the OED as 'a passage, or way through'.

There is a standard international road sign which depicts a matchstick figure with a red line drawn through them. In the UK this sign sometimes reads *NO THOROUGHFARE*.

Comment: Come on. What does this add to my answer?!

Comment: International? It's not used in the U.S., and I assume it's not used in France.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Probably nothing, but I didn't even see your answer before I posted mine. For that matter, what does your answer add to my earlier comment?

Comment: @PeterShor So what? Cricket in an international sport. But you don't see much of it in the USA nor in France!

Comment: The sign in [Australia](http://www.roadsignsaustralia.com.au/ourproducts/TrafficSigns/AustralianStandard/GuideServiceSigns.aspx) seems to be *no through road*, and not *no thoroughfare*. In the U.S., the standard warning is *not a through street*. But *no thoroughfare* is certainly used in more than one country, so I guess *international* applies.

Comment: @WS2 An entire OED definition. But comments are not answers, and my answer still beat your comment by 40 seconds.

Comment: @PeterShor But I am told that in the Isle of Man and the the Scilly Isles *NO THOROUGHFARE* signs are the order of the day. When I said 'international' I was actually referring to that part of the sign which shows a little matchstick man with a red line drawn through him. I have amended my answer for clarity.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Sometimes life really is a pig!

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia entry for "gracht", [Gracht](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gracht) is lengthy and says "The word is almost untranslatable; for that reason the following terms kanaal, vaart, gracht and singel will be discussed here first," and also, "There is no direct equivalent for "gracht" in the English language, therefore it is best left untranslated." So I'm guessing there is no good answer to your question.

Comment: OP didn't ask the equivalent/translation of _gracht_.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question mentions "gracht," I believe Jon C is not asking for a translation of that word, but rather one word that is a synonym for all kinds of structures that allow land-based travel.

I nominate, **road**, **way**, or possibly **path**. I prefer "way" but my reasoning might be odd.

In religions and philosophies that have roots in Hinduism--Buddhism, Daoism, and Confucianism--there is an important concept that is named *dao* in Chinese (or *tao*, hence Daoism, Taoism, and the *Tao Te Ching*). Dao is almost always translated as "way" but sometimes as "path" or "road." The centrality of this concept in multiple languages suggests to me that it is a word that encompasses many ideas: it is a synonym for many words.

Similarly, in Arabic, the word *shar'* means "path or way [especially to the watering hole]". That word is exceptionally important because it is the root word of one of the most well-known Arabic words *sharia*. Again, because an important word in a major language is typically translated as path, way, or road in English, I believe that points to the centrality of those words in English when describing structures for land-based transportation.

I believe the etymology of the [way](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=way&allowed_in_frame=0), [road](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=road&allowed_in_frame=0), and [path](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=path&allowed_in_frame=0) also supports that "way" is best term.

> Old English weg "road, path; course of travel; room, space, freedom of
>   movement;" also, figuratively, "course of life" ...
>
> From c.1300 as "manner in which something occurs." Adverbial
>   constructions attested since Middle English include this way "in this
>   direction," that way "in that direction," ...
>
> ...From the "course 
>   of travel" sense comes the figurative go separate ways (1837); one way
>   or (the) other (1550s); have it both ways (1847); and the figurative
>   sense of come a long way (1922).
>
> Adverbial phrase all the way "completely, to conclusion" is by 1915;
>   ... Way out
>   "means of exit" is from 1926. Encouragement phrase way to go is short
>   for that's the way to go.

**Conclusion: In English, I believe "way" is the best literal and metaphorical description for the general act of traveling and the structure on which a person is traveling.**

Comment: What an interesting answer!